# After one landscape page, I do not get a proper portrait (fullpage)

Tags: geometry, landscape, pdflscape, fullpage, lscape

In my document (exam) I want one page in landscape - which works perfectly. Now, the following pages are reduced to a quadratic format (notice that page number is about 8cm too high). What can I do?

I use overleaf. I switched between lscape and pdflscape but I get the same result.
[image]

Comment: showing a list of packages does not allow anyone to debug your problem which is most likely related to the markup on the page with the probelm, please show a small but complete document that shows the bad page size.

Comment: on your packages you don't need inputenc, you should only use T1 fontenc with pdflatex and you should only use fontspec with lualatex or xelatex, so one of those packages is wrong. You don't need to load amsmath as you are loading mathtools

Comment: Why you delete information about your document? Well, they was not complete as we wish to be. You should extend showed code fragment to complete small document, which reproduce your  problem. Now is impossible to help you. We haven't any clue what is going on in your document.

Comment: It seems tat this is bug in `exam` package. See if you can replace `landscape` environment by `sidewaystable` or `sidewaysfigure` defined in `rotating` package.